# Why are fluid simulations so hard?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations

Fluid simulations solving the hydrodynamic (HD) or the magneto-hydrodynamic (MHD) equations are very useful in physics, the latter being particularly useful for modeling plasmas.

Of course these equations are highly nonlinear and solving them accurately is difficult. My first question is, in the general case **what some specific numerical challenges for building good fluid simulations solving HD/MHD**?

I am also interested in the specific case of modeling multiphase gases, like those that appear in galaxy halos. **What are the specific numerical challenges in this case?**

Comment: Questions about the computational challenges are probably better suited to Computational Science SE. Questions about building physical models are good here.

Comment: @sammygerbil the thing is the numerical challenges come from the equations themselves, and from physics problems like turbulence. So it seems appropriate.

Comment: Solving equations is a question about analytical mathematics or numerical algorithms. The physics comes through constructing or interpreting the equation (modelling). Computational Science SE specialises in algorithms for numerical solutions.

Comment: ObXKCD: https://m.xkcd.com/1851/

Comment: What sammy said. I guess asking about the underlying physics of why it's hard to do is on-topic here, but the details of how to actually deal with those issues is more suited to Computational Science.

Comment: Turbulence on its own in a virtually incompressible fluid is hard enough to model numerically. But when you've got all those funky different modes for energy to go into it's worse than herding cats... in a space with too many dimensions.

Comment: The computational approaches used in this type of problem typically use something of the physics in their construction, especially as the equations become more complex.  It's not clear-cut to decouple the physics from the computation in such cases. @PM2Ring The question may be broad or opinion-based, but I think it's got sufficient physics content.

Comment: Have you considered using commercially available computational fluid dynamics software?

Comment: @Brick Sure, it's got plenty of physics content and I have no intention of close-voting it, at this stage. I'm just trying to steer the focus towards the physical principles aspects, and away from the *specific* numerical computational challenges aspects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a short list of the main challenges in solving magnetohydrodynamic equations accurately on a computer.

First of all, as you point out, the equations are strongly nonlinear because (for example) the constituitive relationships in the model contain nonconstant coefficients. This is not too much of a problem on a computer because you can replace a constant with a value that gets adjusted and updated for every time slice in the simulation, but you either have to calculate the new constant and then plug it into the model or have a look-up table on hand that the program uses for the updates. Either of these things adds complexity to the calculations needed to clank the simulation forward in time.

Second, you have differential equations for newton's laws, navier-stokes law, the gaseous equation of state, ohm's law, heat transfer, and maxwell's equations to solve that are all coupled together: for a given mass element in the plasma, you have to sum the magnetic, electrostatic, inertial, friction, and pressure forces acting on it, and each depends on the others in ways that you can't neglect- and this makes that system of equations very hard to solve.

Third, for best accuracy you have to divide the system into the smallest volume or mass elements and the smallest time slices possible to ensure you have captured all the relevant physics. All the coupled, nonlinear differential equations then have to be solved for every one of those tiny volume elements, at each of the tiny dT's, in order to advance the solution one time step. A system model's computational complexity hence scales with the 3rd power of the length scale in the model which blows up the time required to compute one time step, and doubling the time resolution of the model doubles the time required to solve it.

All these things conspire against the model-writer, and require him or her to use a net of interconnected supercomputers to do the job- and a truly gigantic amount of dynamic memory in which to store the intermediate results of every dT in the model.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Does turbulence created added difficulty numerically?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that your compute volume elements have to be smaller than the characteristic scale length of the turbulence by at least a factor of 2 and preferably 5 and ideally 10.